# How to put an image within a select option?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of pictures people can choose from, and I want to put them within a  list; however, how can I make each option in the select list an image instead of text?

Comment: @adeneo I could have sworn I've seen it somewhere. :(

Comment: Make your own list element

Comment: @Justin - only in custom made dropdowns, not the native select. Head on over to http://www.tv.com/ and type something in the search box on the top right side.

Comment: @adeneo Thank you. I appreciate the response. :)